# Angular - Using 'data' attribute to tag array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm using angular to deal with navigation in an application that I am working on. I have started tagging some elements of the application using the 'data' attribute so that certain user roles shall not have access to them. My problem is coming in when I want to use the same attribute to dictate the structure of the array so that certain users cannot view the configurations. So how can I use the 'data' attribute to hide certain elements of an array in Angular?

Thanks

Comment: i'm not sure to understand your question. you can use `<span ng-show='data.attributeA == value'></span>` to show an element in html

Comment: It's hard to help you without any code sample...